# Is $(ab) ^2\leq (\frac{a^2+b^2}{2})^2 $ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

I have shown,

$$ab \leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}. $$

As a general question if square both sides, then for $(ab) ^2\leq (\frac{a^2+b^2}{2})^2 $ to be true,

$$2|ab|\leq a^2+b^2 $$ would have to be true, right?

Is the last statement true, if so how would I be able to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that for $x^2\leq y^2$ to be true, we must have $|x|\leq|y|$, since $x^2=|x|^2$ and the square function is strictly increasing for positive inputs. As others have pointed out, this is the case for the expression you gave, since
$$
2|ab|\leq (a^2+b^2)
$$
IS in fact true. As others have pointed out, the above inequality can be shown by considering the expressions $(a\pm b)^2=a^2+b^2\pm2ab$.

Answer (score 3):

One has
$$
(a \pm b)^2 = a^2 \pm 2ab + b^2 \geq 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a^2 + b^2 \geq \mp 2ab
$$
and so $2|ab| \leq a^2 + b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If both
$u \ge 0$
and
$v \ge 0$
then
$u \le v$
implies
$u^2 \le v^2$.

Proof:
Since
$u \le v$
then
$v-u \ge 0$.
Therefore
$v^2-u^2
=(v-u)(v+u)
\ge 0
$
since
$v-u \ge 0$
and
$v+u \ge 0$
(since both are
$\ge 0$).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(a-b)^2\geqslant 0$ so that

$$ a^2-2ab+b^2\geqslant 0$$ 
which is

$$ \dfrac{a^2+b^2}2 \geqslant ab$$

that is, what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

$(a+b)^2 \geq 0$.

Then $a^2 +2ab+ b^2 \geq 0$.

Then $a^2 + b^2 \geq 2ab$.

By definition, $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$. We have: $|a^2+b^2| \geq |2ab|$.

Since $a^2 + b^2$ is positive even without the absolute value sign, we have: $a^2 + b^2 \geq 2|ab|$. We can isolate 2 because $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$.